# How to uniformly sample a big graph?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, graph-algorithm, random

I have a big graph which has around 4M nodes. The graph consists of two files, one containing the node names and one containing edges (each line represents one edge). I want to uniformly sample the graph nodes and come up with a sample as big as 15% of the whole graph. Considering the size of the graph, what is the best (or maybe possible) way to generate such a sample?

Comment: You want to sample just the nodes or the subgraph (nodes + corresponding edges) that those nodes define?

Comment: Actually yhe subgraph, that is the graph that sampled nodes form.

Answer (score 0):

Use this java code to select 15% of the vertices randomly:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class RandomSample {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (Math.random()<0.15)
            context.write(value,null);
        else
            context.write(null,null);
    context.write(value,null);
    } 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "randomsample");
    job.setJarByClass(RandomSample.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

And use this bash script to run it

```
echo "Running Job"
hadoop jar RandomSample.jar RandomSample $1 tmp
echo "copying result to local path (RandomSample)"
hadoop fs -getmerge tmp RandomSample
echo "Clean up"
hadoop fs -rmr tmp
```

For example, if we name the script random_sample.sh, to select 15% from folder /example/, simply run

```
./random_sample.sh /example/
```

Then, you can use simple `grep` operation on the second file to select only edges that contains the randomly chosen vertices